# Script to write the path followed to open a file

Tags: vba, excel

I have a code to open a file, copy it, and paste it to another file. However, the file name being copied is subject to change, depending on the accounting period, so I'm looking for a script that will anticipate this change. The idea being that the Period name will be inserted somewhere within a Workfile, let's say in A2 of Sheet1. The VBA will then be run read this cell to determine which folder and spreadsheet to open.

This is the standard script for opening, copying and pasting the spreadsheet:

```
Sub Import_Headcount()
'
' Import_Headcount Macro
'
'
    Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
        "Q:\Accounts Department\JM Period End ADI\1516\Stats\Period 04\Headcount P4.xlsx"
    Cells.Select
    Range("A2081").Activate
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("Stat Accounts - Workfile.xlsm").Activate
    Sheets("Headcount").Select
    Cells.Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Sheets("Input Page").Select
    Windows("Headcount P4.xlsx").Activate
    ActiveWindow.Close
End Sub
```

It is the "Period 4" and the "P4" (of Headcount P4) that is subject to change depending on cell A2.

Can a script be written to determine the path that is followed to open a file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
        "Q:\Accounts Department\JM Period End ADI\1516\Stats\Period " & range("a1").value & "\Headcount P" & range("a1").value & ".xlsx"
```

Something like this....

Comment: You sir, are a diamond! Thank you so much, it's spot on.

Comment: @FISHED - If this answers your question, you should mark the answer `Accepted`